# Detect matched items in a list efficiently

Tags: .net, pattern-matching

I've got a list of audiobook parts that looks something like..

```
20,000 Leagues Under The Sea
A Tale of Two Cities Part 1 of 2
A Tale of Two Cities Part 2 of 2
A Canterbury Tale 1
A Canterbury Tale 2
Great Expectations
```

And I'm trying to collapse the list similar to Db normalisation...

```
20,000 Leagues Under The Sea
    (Parts = {"20,000 Leagues Under The Sea"})
A Tale of Two Cities
    (Parts = {"A Tale of Two Cities Part 1 of 2", "A Tale of Two Cities Part 2 of 2"})
A Canterbury Tale
    (Parts = {"A Canterbury Tale 1", "A Canterbury Tale 2"})
Great Expectations
    (Parts = {"Great Expectations"})
```

Now, I could pull out all those entries ending in certain patterns of numbers but I'd need to handle quite a few formats (`1/2`, `1 of 2`, or just `2`). After removing the numbers, I can strip any optional "Part",

But that all seems a little clunky. It feels like there should be a better way to identify the groups - perhaps something along the lines of "Find entries which differ only in the last n characters"?

Can someone please point me at an elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a trie..? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Comment: @thebjorn It does indeed - although only with 2 levels. How do you generate one without using a dictionary? Is there a convenient algorithm?

Comment: Google can give you many algorithms and research papers, but you could look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/is-this-a-reasonable-trie-implementation for inspiration (although it does use a Dictionary...)

Comment: @thebjorn Thanks for the link but that's an awful lot of code for the sake of removing a 5-6 line kludge. Perhaps I'm better off where I am

Answer (score 1):

If your 5-6 line kluge works, why not keep it?

This is a rather difficult problem in the general case because there are so many different ways to mark the different episodes. We solved it to some degree with YouTube videos, but it was far from perfect. As you say, there are many different formats, although they take one of two general forms:

```
<name><episode>
<episode><name>
```

is the name of the book/video series, and  can take many forms. But even those *typically* are:

```
[word]<epidose-number>[of][<total-episodes>]
```

[word] is optional and may be any of several words: "part," "episode," "installment," "scene," etc. [of] usually exists and is typically "of," "/", "-", etc. Sometimes authors would mix formats for the same series. The problem is further complicated by inconsistent naming. So you'll see:

```
My vacation, part 1 of 3
Vacation, tape 2
Part 3 of my vacation
```

To the extent that you can standardize your episode naming and numbering, the problem becomes easier to solve. The solution we arrived at used a dictionary, but you can do it with sorting. Our solution was, basically:

- For each video, derive the name and the episode number. (We used a custom parser and some heuristics for this, but you could use regular expressions if the number of different episode numbering schemes is reasonably small. The harder part for us was matching up names, but if you assume that there are no typos in the names, this is tractable.)
- Create an object instance from those two pieces of data
- Add that instance to the list of all items

Once we did that, it was a simple matter to sort the list by name and episode.

The solution you choose will depend entirely on how clean your data is. If it's reasonably clean with just a handful of different episode formats, I'd strongly suggest a regular expression solution.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I've got an advantage in that all the episodes of a particular audiobook will be in the same format (Not that that's neccesarily a sane format but there you go). At the moment, if I find anything that looks like it ends with a `n of m` in various formats, I try to stem it to the episode name and pick out similar ones - it seems to work about 90% of the time so maybe I just need to extend it to cover more corner cases (Mostly broken by spurious text after the episode numbering). Thanks for your assistance